# `npm install` command failing in the azure build pipelines for basic angular app

Tags: angular, azure, npm, azure-pipelines

1. Imported [this](https://github.com/alexfriesen/cv/tree/master) GitHub Repository to the Azure Repository.
2. Created the Build Pipeline using Classic Editor and its YAML Code is in below:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/master
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    fetchDepth: 1
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: npm install
    inputs:
      workingDir: package.json
      verbose: false
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: npm custom
    inputs:
      command: custom
      workingDir: package.json
      verbose: false
      customCommand: npm run build
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: Archive $(Build.BinariesDirectory)
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

Not Sure, what went wrong. It is giving the error in `npm install` step when running the pipelines:

[image]

**Error in Text**:

```
Starting: npm install
==============================================================================
Task         : npm
Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Azure Artifacts.
Version      : 1.221.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm
==============================================================================
/usr/local/bin/npm --version
9.5.1
##[error]Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/package.json/.npmrc'
```

Comment: You've set the working directory to package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it worked by 2 ways, In order for your YAML pipeline to read the code from your repository you need to use [**predefined variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) In order to read your file from repository you need to use `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` in your code.

When I just tried using package.json or even $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/package.json, I received the same error code:-

[image]

Now, I used below **Code-1** and it worked successfully, Refer below:-

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest


steps:
  - checkout: self
    fetchDepth: 1
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: npm install
    inputs:
      workingDir: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
      verbose: false
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: Archive $(Build.BinariesDirectory)
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Code-2:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build 
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: Archive $(Build.BinariesDirectory)

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I solved myself using 2nd method and now 1st method also helpful.

Comment: @Prasad Upvoted, glad the answer was helpful!